# select distinct where max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 a table named "maintenances" and another "processes" and "cars". 
maintenances:

```
id   car_id   process_id   date
1     1        1           4/26/2013
2     1        1           5/26/2013
3     1        2           5/26/2013
```

I want to select distinct values for car_id and process_id repeated based on max date. So I want:

```
id   car_id   process_id   date
2    1          1          5/26/2013
3    1          1          5/26/2013
```

I have this:

```
SELECT m.*, u.username, c.milage, p.*, s.name
                                    FROM maintenances as m
                                         LEFT JOIN users AS u
                                         ON u.id = m.user_id 
                                         LEFT JOIN cars AS c
                                         ON c.id = m.car_id
                                         LEFT JOIN processes as p
                                         ON p.id = m.process_id
                                         LEFT JOIN services as s
                                         ON s.id = m.service_id
                                    Group by m.car_id, m.process_id
```

But this gives me :

```
id   car_id   process_id   date
 1    1          1          4/26/2013
 3    1          2          5/26/2013
```

I want:

```
 id   car_id   process_id   date
  2    1          1          5/26/2013
  3    1          2          5/26/2013
```

Comment: from the given data what is the logic behind getting the row `3    1          1          5/26/2013`

Comment: you want process_id 2 on second line, no ?

Comment: what about max(date) with group by car_id,process_id

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Just edited my question. I was making a little mistake. Pls take a look

Comment: @Sadikhasan where to put max(date) ?

Comment: @user3660185 do you really need to do `m.*, u.username, c.milage, p.*, s.name` or do you want only the fields shown in your `sample desired results` ? By the way, where does date come from ? I would say from process, but not sure ?

Comment: the structure you provided is incomplete. More over you are selecting many columns in query but displaying only some of them which we do not know to which table they belong

Comment: try "order by date" after group by

Comment: from where to select date at the place put max(date)

Comment: @Sadikhasan date is a column of "maintenance". And  there are many columns and I couldn't display them all. The problem is how to select distinct car_id , process_id and max date for that distinct

Comment: @vaibhav tried but didn't gave me what I want. The result was the same

Comment: @raheel shan I can't show all columns there are so many. date is coming from "maintenances" table (m.*)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus I want all the fields in my query. Just mentioned the fields on which the query should return the result. I can't show all columns there are many

Comment: Unless the id and date is functionally dependent of your group by clause (car_id, process_id) you will get a "random row".

Answer (score 3):

Try to join `maintenances` with a subquery with `MAX(date)`:

```
  SELECT m.*, u.username, c.milage, p.*, s.name
  FROM maintenances as m
  JOIN 
      (SELECT car_id, process_id, MAX(date) as MAX_DATE 
       FROM maintenances  
       GROUP BY by car_id, process_id) as MAX_T ON m.car_id = MAX_T.car_id 
                    AND m.process_id = MAX_T.process_id 
                    AND m.date = MAX_T.MAX_DATE
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN cars AS c ON c.id = m.car_id
  LEFT JOIN processes AS p ON p.id = m.process_id
  LEFT JOIN services AS s ON s.id = m.service_id
```